# Referring to data frame columns (without referring to the data frame) inside a function in R?

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

I would like to refer to data frame columns inside a function by their names (just write columnname), but not write df$columnname or df["columnname"] every time

This can be achieved using attach() function, but I have heard that it is slow etc.

So far I have achieved something like this:

```
> somefunction <- function(df1,df2) {attach(df1); attach(df2); mean(Sepal.Length) + speed*3}
> somefunction(iris, cars)
The following objects are masked from iris:

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from b (pos = 5):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from a (pos = 6):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from a (pos = 8):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from cars:

    dist, speed

The following objects are masked from b (pos = 8):

    dist, speed

 [1] 17.84333 17.84333 26.84333 26.84333 29.84333 32.84333 35.84333 35.84333 35.84333 38.84333 38.84333 41.84333 41.84333 41.84333 41.84333 44.84333
[17] 44.84333 44.84333 44.84333 47.84333 47.84333 47.84333 47.84333 50.84333 50.84333 50.84333 53.84333 53.84333 56.84333 56.84333 56.84333 59.84333
[33] 59.84333 59.84333 59.84333 62.84333 62.84333 62.84333 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 71.84333 74.84333 77.84333 77.84333 77.84333
[49] 77.84333 80.84333
```

And if I call the function again...

```
> somefunction(iris, cars)
The following objects are masked from df1 (pos = 4):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from iris:

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from b (pos = 7):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from a (pos = 8):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from a (pos = 10):

    Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

The following objects are masked from df2 (pos = 4):

    dist, speed

The following objects are masked from cars:

    dist, speed

The following objects are masked from b (pos = 10):

    dist, speed

 [1] 17.84333 17.84333 26.84333 26.84333 29.84333 32.84333 35.84333 35.84333 35.84333 38.84333 38.84333 41.84333 41.84333 41.84333 41.84333 44.84333
[17] 44.84333 44.84333 44.84333 47.84333 47.84333 47.84333 47.84333 50.84333 50.84333 50.84333 53.84333 53.84333 56.84333 56.84333 56.84333 59.84333
[33] 59.84333 59.84333 59.84333 62.84333 62.84333 62.84333 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 71.84333 74.84333 77.84333 77.84333 77.84333
[49] 77.84333 80.84333
```

Those pos values seem to change, which is not good (or is it?).

Anyway, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These objects are being `attach`ed into the global environment:

```r
somefunction <- function(df1,df2) {attach(df1); attach(df2); mean(Sepal.Length) + speed*3}
somefunction(iris, cars)
#>  [1] 17.84333 17.84333 26.84333 26.84333 29.84333 32.84333 35.84333 35.84333
#>  [9] 35.84333 38.84333 38.84333 41.84333 41.84333 41.84333 41.84333 44.84333
#> [17] 44.84333 44.84333 44.84333 47.84333 47.84333 47.84333 47.84333 50.84333
#> [25] 50.84333 50.84333 53.84333 53.84333 56.84333 56.84333 56.84333 59.84333
#> [33] 59.84333 59.84333 59.84333 62.84333 62.84333 62.84333 65.84333 65.84333
#> [41] 65.84333 65.84333 65.84333 71.84333 74.84333 77.84333 77.84333 77.84333
#> [49] 77.84333 80.84333
dist
#>  [1]   2  10   4  22  16  10  18  26  34  17  28  14  20  24  28  26  34  34  46
#> [20]  26  36  60  80  20  26  54  32  40  32  40  50  42  56  76  84  36  46  68
#> [39]  32  48  52  56  64  66  54  70  92  93 120  85
Sepal.Length
#>   [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1
#>  [19] 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0
#>  [37] 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0 6.4 6.9 5.5
#>  [55] 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1
#>  [73] 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5
#>  [91] 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3
#> [109] 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7 6.0 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2
#> [127] 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8
#> [145] 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9
```

You would need to `detach` them or you're likely to cause nasty errors for users.

You'll also have to ensure that this happens if your function errors or is interrupted, eg using `on.exit`.

Generally I think you should reconsider whether using `attach` is worth the headache of difficult bugs, over simply writing `df$variable`...

The documentation for `attach` even covers this:

```
In programming, functions should not change the search path unless 
that is their purpose.  Often ‘with’ can be used within a
function. If not, good practice is to

    • Always use a distinctive ‘name’ argument, and

    • To immediately follow the ‘attach’ call by an ‘on.exit’ call
      to ‘detach’ using the distinctive name.
```

Comment: Yes, the nested with() functions is the way to go here. Is there a way I could write like:
with(df1, df2, {contents of the function}) rather that writing with(df1, with(df2, {contents}))?